# Power Pivot - Get previous Year sum

Tags: excel, powerpivot, excel-2019

I have a table with these headers:

DeptName - ActualFees - Month - Year

I want to see in a chat the Deptname and the amount, according to a slicer to select the year, plus the previous year. I have tried a few codes but none worked. The Year column is not in a date format.

I already tried:

```
SUMX (Table, Table[Year]=Table[Year]-1
```

---

```
Calculate( Sum(Table[ActualFee], Table[Year]=Table[Year]-1)
```

---

```
SUMX( Filter(Table,
      Table[Year] = Table[Year]-1,
      Table[ActualFees])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
=VAR thisYear = VALUES(Table1[Year])
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(Table1[Year]),CALCULATE(SUM([ActualFees]),ALL(Table1[YEAR]),Table1[Year]=thisYear-1),blank())
```

Comment: Wow. It worked just fine yeah, I really appreciate! I'm not trying to understand the structure. Thank you Rory!